# What is the "root element" for rem?

Tags: html, css

W3 [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem):

> Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element. When specified on the font-size property of the root element, the rem units refer to the property’s initial value.

What is this "root element" referring to? `<html>`? `<body>`?

Comment: Most of informations you can find (references, articles, etc.) tell clearly that `<html>` is the root element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-root-element).

For an HTML document, the root element is `<html>`.

See also [the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-root):

> There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element.] For all other elements, if the start-tag is in the content of another element, the end-tag is in the content of the same element.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've seen a lot of people set `html, body { font-size: 20px; }`, which made me think that sometimes `html` is treated as root, and sometimes `body` is. So rem never treats `body` as root right? Do you know of a reason they'd use both the `html` and the `body` selectors?

Comment: @AdamZerner — I've vague recollections of quirks mode behaviour where font size inheritance doesn't work quite right. It's most likely either due to old browser bugs, cargo culting or a combination of the two.

Answer (score -1):

All bodies of web with html standards start with `<html>`.This is why the root element is html tag. Even if you remove html tag from a html file and open it using browser, you can check the code by `inspect element` feature that browsers added html tags for you.

Comment: You are confusing _elements_ with _tags_. _Tags_ are used in the source text to mark the beginning and end of _elements_. The `HTML` (and `HEAD` and `BODY`) _elements_ are always present in an HTML document. Their _tags_ however, are entirely optional and the browser will open and close the elements as needed. For example, the only time you actually _need_ a `</head>` or `<body>` tag is when you want to start the `BODY` element with an element that is also allowed inside the `HEAD` element.